# Build Table on one sheet with data from multiple sheets and varying column length

Tags: vba, excel

I need to build a table on one sheet by pulling data from 15 sheets (1 at a time). These sheets are separated by date. The date is in one cell. The other data "Name", "Shift", "Station", "Product", "Package", "Capacity" and "Performance" can have varying column lengths from sheet to sheet (as we move across the dates). On building the table I want to record the date on every row that matches the data taken from its sheet. 
I started with the code below by trying to select the first data cell of each data column and want to move down the column until there is a blank cell and select that portion to transfer it to the table. 
This is going to be a long code and I want get one thing right at a time, I will ask more questions as it develops. This is my first one-- How can I adjust the code to select the column to pick up information by selecting data until I get to a blank cell?

Thanks,

```
Sub DataTable()
Dim rcell1, rcell2, rcell3, rcell4, rcell5, recell6, rcell7, rcell8 As Long

    Worksheets("1").Activate
    Range("G4").Select
    rcell1 = Selection.Value ' Date

    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Name 
    rcell2 = Selection.Value 

    Range("C9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Shift 
    rcell3 = Selection.Value 

    Range("D9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Station
    rcell4 = Selection.Value 

    Range("E9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Product
    rcell5 = Selection.Value 

    Range("F9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Package
    rcell6 = Selection.Value 

    Range("O9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Capacity 
    rcell7 = Selection.Value 

    Range("Q9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select ' Performance
    rcell8 = Selection.Value 

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should give you good start and loop through each worksheet (notice how the case checks the name of the sheet). You'll also need to update any range references that I may have assumed.

```
Sub DataTable()


Dim wsTable As Worksheet
Set wsTable = Worksheets("Table") 'change as needed

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name

        Case Is = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ' etc.

            With ws

                Dim rngData As Range
                Set rngData = Union(.Range("B:F"), .Range("O:O"), .Range("Q:Q"))

                Dim lRow As Long
                Dim rCheck As Range
                For Each rCheck In Intersect(rngData, .Rows(1))

                    If .Cells(.Rows.Count, rCheck.Column).End(xlUp).Row > lRow Then
                         lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rCheck.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                     End If

                Next


                Dim dDate As Date
                dDate = .Range("G4").Value

                With wsTable

                    .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(lRow, 1).Value = dDate
                    ws.Range("B9:F" & lRow).Copy 
                   .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    ws.Range("O9:O" & lRow).Copy 
                    .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    ws.Range("Q9:O" & lRow).Copy 
                    .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                End With

            End With

    End Select

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I adjusted the code but could not get it to run fully. I have copied the code below as I have it in VBA. I get an error: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. This occurs at the line, Set rngData = Union(.Range("B:F"), .Range("O"), .Range("Q")). 

The only spots I changed were


Set wsTable = Worksheets("Efficiency") 'change as needed

and 

Case Is = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"

I assume "Case Is" is the worksheet name.

Comment: @kish - see my edits on that line. apologies for the syntax error.

Comment: Scott it worked, but there are three issues. 1. When the date is transferred to the table, the first date cell in the column overwrites the column title. 2. there is mismatch between the date and the data that matches it, the data column can be of inconsistent length as it goes from day to day (sheet to sheet). I need the number of date rows to be only as much as the data rows available on each day; and 3; the format ting (cell colors and borders) of the table on the day to day sheet shows up on the final table. I want to see only the data.

Comment: @Kish - see my edits inside the `With wsTable` block to address points 1 and 3. For point 2, the `lRow` variable in this line `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(lRow, 1).Value` should fill the dates to the exact number of rows found for each sheet. Perhaps because the code was written in a way that overwrote the column header inside of moving one cell down was throwing the date rows off as well (because on each date it will overwrite the last cell of the previous date. The fix I made for point 1 may address this as well. But if not, you can easily debug based on the data.

Comment: We have made progress but there are some more bugs. In the line, lRow = rngData.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row, the code is looking for anything in these cells. It is picking up the cell formatting as well, which is a color coded table. I want to search only for data or text.  Next, the table formatting from which we are pulling data goes up to cell 20 from cell 9. On the table that we are building I notice that the date fills up 20 rows after the title row...

Comment: @kish - see my edits. you're starting to state problems that were not in your original question. If you have more questions, please post a new question so this particular thread does not become too unwieldy and unclear.

Comment: OK I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define each individual column. What you should so is use "UsedRange" to select all columns/rows that have data, and assign the values to a 2D Array, which can then be manipulated using loops.

Comment: fwiw, I find that rectangular blocks of data are better referenced with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) than the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that could work, but what happens if a column or row has a blank in it, with more data after it? UsedRange captures everything.

Comment: For CurrentRegion to miss data an entire row or entire column would have to be blank. CurrentRegion works on 'islands' of data which extend in all directions until a full blank row or column is met. The method can be demonstrated manually on a worksheet by selecting a cell and tapping [Ctrl]+A once. With rectangular islands of data there are usually column header labels with discount the 'fully blank column' and fully blank rows generally indicate bad data, not a normal situation.

Comment: Thank you for the input here. CurrentRegion is useful.